# Joomla: Blank site when uninstall a component

Tags: joomla

I have installed [AdvancedModuleManager](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedmodulemanager?) while trying to assign modules to certain pages. However It did not work as I wanted and when I tried to uninstall it from the Administration panel - the website gone blank.

Both /administrator/ and front end are blank.

Any ideas how to fix it?

```
[22-Apr-2016 21:25:36 Europe/Sofia] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home/public_html/libraries/regularlabs/helpers/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/public_html/plugins/system/sourcerer/sourcerer.php on line 41
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have installed another Plugin called "Sourcerer".

Both "Sourcerer" and "Advanced module Manager" are made from "Regular Labs" and when I uninstalled the AMM I also uninstalled their common component called Regular Labs Library...

Installed it again and everything was fine